# Как в редьюсере типизировать возращаемое из метода map значение?

Tags: массивы, reactjs, redux

объведённое значения массива тасок-как правильно типизировать?Возращаемый тип initialtype  не работает,через дженерик не получает[![][2]][2]ся так там двоеточие через as <.> тоже.Если вместо tasks  намеренно написать task - тайп скрипт это пропускает.. но в последствии  ошибка всплывает в пропсах в компоненте

[image: обведённое значения массива]

Answer (score 0):

```
const x = [{}].map( i => i as number)
```